# flatten list of list through list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to flatten a list using list comprehension in python. My list is somewhat like

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, 8]
```

just for printing then individual item in this list of list I wrote this function:

```
def flat(listoflist):
    for item in listoflist:
        if type(item) != list:
            print(item)
        else:
            for num in item:
                print(num)
```

interactive output:

```
>>> flat(list1)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Then I used the same logic to flatten my list through list comprehension I am getting the following error

```
list2 = [item if type(item) != list else num for num in item for item in list1]
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I flatten this type of list-of-list using using list comprehension ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: in pseudocode, `flatten(xs) = [ y | for x from xs , for y from ( if (type x == list) then flatten(x) else [x] ) ]`. now just make it valid Python syntax.

Comment: At what level will the list be nested?

Comment: Anyways posted a solution that works with nested lists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> from itertools import chain
```

One-liner:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item,Iterable) and
                    not isinstance(item, basestring) else [item] for item in lis))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

A readable version:

```
>>> def func(x):                                         #use `str` in py3.x 
...     if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring): 
...         return x
...     return [x]
... 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(func(x) for x in lis))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
#works for strings as well
>>> lis = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, 8, "foobar"]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(func(x) for x in lis))                                                                
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'foobar']
```

Using nested list comprehension:(Going to be slow compared to `itertools.chain`):

```
>>> [ele for item in (func(x) for x in lis) for ele in item]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'foobar']
```

Comment: This is great for the asker using 2.x, but it's worth a note that 3.x users should use `str` instead of `basestring`.

Comment: @Ashwini What should be done if my elements are of type dict instead of integer?

Comment: @AnuragSharma small example?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary for example ---> [[{'ascdd': 'skj'}, {'fd': 'srsr'}], {'dsf': 'ds', 'ds': 'dsffd'}]

Comment: @AnuragSharma what is the expected output for this case?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary expected output ---> [{'ascdd': 'skj'}, {'fd': 'srsr'},{'dsf': 'ds', 'ds': 'dsffd'}] or simply a list of dictionary

Answer (score 28):

No-one has given the usual answer:

```
def flat(l):
  return [y for x in l for y in x]
```

There are dupes of this question floating around StackOverflow.

Comment: Your code does not work for the list the OP provided because his list includes non-iterable objects, namely integers.

Your code does however work if every item in the list is an iterable object.

See my comment below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I'll actually need to find a moment to mess around with that and come to grips...

Comment: Double `for` is interesting. The above problem can also be solved using: `[z for y in [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in [1, [2]]] for z in y]`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to iterate through a number, which you can't do (hence the error).

If you're using python 2.7:

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But do note that the module is now deprecated, and no longer exists in Python 3

Comment: Type checking lists is a bad idea. It makes this much less flexible.

Comment: if `l` is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, 888]`, the first solution yields `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]`.

Comment: Removed the first bit, but it's a shame that my other solution won't work in python 3

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using a generator:

```
import collections

def flatten(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str):  # `basestring` < 3.x
            yield from item  # `for subitem in item: yield item` < 3.3
        else:
            yield item

>>> list(flatten([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7, 8]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def nnl(nl):    # non nested list

    nn = []

    for x in nl:
        if type(x) == type(5):
            nn.append(x)

    if type(x) == type([]):
        n = nnl(x)

        for y in n:
            nn.append(y)
    return nn

print (nnl([[9, 4, 5], [3, 8,[5]], 6]))  # output: [9, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Probably an explanation would be helpful as well.

Comment: This solution uses **recursion.** 
For every element in the nested list you check if the element is an integer or a list. If an integer, we append that integer in the list nn. If the element in the nested list is a list, call a recursive function, you will do to the sublist what you did to the initial nested list. Then append the elements that are not a list again in nn. 
The output of nn will be a non nested list. Happy coding everybody!

Comment: Great! Now please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52006022/edit) adding this information.

Comment: Done - Namasté.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient and fast solution using precision and generators that will also work with highly nested lists.

#### Implementation

```py
def _flatten_list(l: list):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten_list(item)
        else:
            yield item
            
def flatten_list(l: list):
    return list(_flatten_list(l))
        
example = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6], 7], 8, [9, [10]]]
print(flatten_list(example))
```

#### Output

```py
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```