# Python Inline list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

i'd like to do a recursive read on lists

for example, I have the following:

```
[x if x % 2 == 0 else [a for a in [9,8,7]] for x in [2,3,4,5]]
```

And the output is:

```
[2, [9, 8, 7], 4, [9, 8, 7]]
```

But I'd like it to be:

```
[2, 9, 8, 7, 4, 9, 8, 7]
```

Is it possible?

I've tried

```
[x if x % 2 == 0 else a for a in [9,8,7] for x in [2,3,4,5]]
```

And didn't work `[2, 9, 4, 9, 2, 8, 4, 8, 2, 7, 4, 7]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `itertools.chain`? It's fairly unclear what the meaning of your comprehension is supposed to be. A regular, more explicit loop might be more readable here.

Comment: Note that `[a for a in [9, 8, 7]]` is just a fancy way of writing `[9, 8, 7]`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich ahahahahaa!! funny, that's my bad!

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Isn't `[a for a in [9, 8, 7]]` a fancy way of writing `[9, 8, 7][:]`? It is a new list after all. Not that it matters much in this precise context.

Comment: Yes, of course, or `list([9, 8, 7])`. But using the literal [9, 8, 7] creates a new list already, of course. If he used a random iterator instead of a literal list it might mean something, but written as it was it just made the expression harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or without itertools:

```
a = [[x] if x % 2 == 0 else [a for a in [9,8,7]] for x in [2,3,4,5]]
a = [i for x in a for i in x]
print (a)
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks! it works fine and also in one line (just what I needed)

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` takes care of this:

```
from collections import Iterable
from itertools import chain

t =  [x if x % 2 == 0 else [a for a in [9,8,7]] for x in [2,3,4,5]]
final_list = list(chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item,Iterable) and
                    not isinstance(item, basestring) else [item] for item in t))
print(final_list)
```

Source:  [flatten list of list through list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338913/flatten-list-of-list-through-list-comprehension)

EDIT:  The issue with the previous solution was it would only work with arrays with values are the same level (ex.  `[[1,2], [3,4]]`) where as arrays like  `[5, [1,2], [3,4]]` return some chain object because of values at different levels (i.e. `5`).

Comment: This did not work, raised a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
` exception and later printed a empty array!

Comment: Does it throw that error at this line `print(list(chain))` ?

Comment: Yes, I just copied it to a console.