# Reduce dictionary dimension to 1

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several dictionaries that I would like to merge into a `pd.DataFrame`. In order to be able to do that, all the dictionaries need to have a dimension of 1. How can I reduce the dimension of the following dictionary to 1 but so that it remains a dictionary? In cases where there are multiple entries for a dictionary item, it should simply be joined. So `myFunds` should become `'2.0 0.0'`

```
h = {
    'gameStage': 'PreFlop',
    'losses': 0,
    'myFunds': [2.0, '0.0'],
    'myLastBet': 0,
    'peviousRoundCards': ['2S', 'QS'],
    'previousCards': ['2S', 'QS'],
    'previousPot': 0.03,
    'wins': 0
}
```

To be more precise what my problem is: I want to save all properties of an object in a `DataFrame`. For that I do `vars(Object)` which gives me a dictionary, but not all of the entries have the same dimension, so I can't do `DataFrame(vars(Object))` because I get an error. That's why I need to first convert `vars(Object)` into a one dimensional dictionary. But it needs to remain a Dictionary, otherwise I can't convert it into a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Your question title is irrelevant to your question content. Do you want to join the list values?

Comment: relevant questions: [Loop over a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python), [make string from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings-python)

Comment: Yes I want to join the values. See amended question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the items in the dictionary, and them flatten them with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

We basically tell it to iterate over each key/value pair in the dictionary value, turn it to a string (as you can't concatenate an `int` and a `string`), and then put it back in the sictionary

The function `func` is [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17338986/380451) and what it does is makes sure we always have an iterable item

```
from collections import Iterable

def func(x):
    #use str instead of basestring if Python3
    if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
        return x
    return [x]

for key, val in h.items():
    h[key] = " ".join([str(ele) for ele in func(val)])
```

Output of `h` becomes:

```
{
  'gameStage': 'PreFlop', 
  'losses': '0', 
  'myFunds': '2.0 0.0', 
  'myLastBet': '0',
  'peviousRoundCards': '2S QS', 
  'previousCards': '2S QS',
  'previousPot': '0.03',
  'wins': '0'
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the list comprehension. You can make it a generator: `" ".join(str(ele) for ele in val)`

Comment: Some values aren't lists.

Comment: NameError: global name 'Iterable' is not defined

Comment: @Nicolas you need to make sure you do `from collections import Iterable`

Comment: @Parker, you are using a list one way or another, I would keep the list comp, if you pass a generator to join python will build a list anyway.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham okay, done. May I ask if there is a reason? Performance? Or just more pythonic and easier to understand?

Comment: It is faster, python does two passes over the object you pass in so if you pass a generator a list is going to be built anyway so there is no real advantage using a gen exp and it ends up being slower