# Writing a list comprehension to flatten a nested list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a nested list mixed with list and numbers.

```
nested = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9], 10, 11]
```

The nested lists only contain numbers, they'll never contain more lists.

Is it possible to write a list comprehension to make new list from the 'nested' list, producing the following output?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

This was my attempt( code is not working)

```
[num if isinstance(item, list) for num in item else item for item in nested]
```

Comment: You don't have a regular list, complicating matters. How irregular is your list going to be?

Comment: This my exact list  [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8] , [9,] , 10 , 11 ]

Comment: That's not what I asked. Will your nested lists ever contain *more* lists?

Comment: No , the inner list is normal list its not nested one.

Comment: Closely related, but the arbitrary nesting leaves a list comprehension option right out: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](//stackoverflow.com/q/2158395)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put your instance test in a loop, so you can extract the elements from a nested list:

```
[num for item in nested for num in (item if isinstance(item, list) else (item,))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> nested = nested = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9], 10, 11]
>>> [num for item in nested for num in (item if isinstance(item, list) else (item,))]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

It helps if you first express this as a set of `for` loops; your attempt essentially did this:

```
for item in nested:
    _element = num if isinstance(item, list) for num in item else item
    result.append(_element)
```

which is not really valid Python.

My list comprehension above instead does this:

```
for item in nested:
    _iterable = item if isinstance(item, list) else (item,)
    for num in _iterable:
        _element = num
        result.append(_element)
```

Comment: Great answer, It does not account for a list containing tuples or a iterable containers and non iterable objects as a usage note...

Comment: @dawg: no, because that's outside the requirements of the question, it's why I asked for the clarifications on the post and ultimately duped this to a different post from the one I link to in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If your list has arbitrary nesting, best to use a recursive function ([referring to one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176969/298607)):

```
>>> def flat_gen(x):
...     def iselement(e):
...         return not(isinstance(e, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(e, str))
...     for el in x:
...         if iselement(el):
...             yield el
...         else:
...             yield from flat_gen(el)   
... 
>>> nested = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8] , [9,] , 10 , 11 ]

>>> import collections
>>> list(flat_gen(nested))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

If you just have mixed nesting between a simple list or tuple (any iterable container) and non list or tuple objects (i.e., non-iterable objects and iterable containers with no deeper nesting) you can use a generator expression with `list`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item,collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str) else [item] for item in nested))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: The OP asked for a list comprehension, otherwise we could just as much have duped to the question you based this on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a clear dupe anyway, no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338913/flatten-list-of-list-through-list-comprehension

Comment: @StefanPochmann: interesting, had not seen that one. And there is no correct list comprehension answer there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I believe that one allows for more nesting though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so. The question contains printing code which can't handle deeper nesting and the question makes it sound like that's working.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: ah, I actually missed that Ashwini includes a list comp version (but made matters more complicated by using a separate function to wrap single elements in a sequence and a nested generator expression).

Comment: @MartijnPieters And the accepted answer doesn't do deeper nesting, either, and still got accepted. But yeah, odd that none of the seven answers there does a list comprehension like yours.