# Can I flatten a list using recursive function and list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, recursion, list-comprehension

This is only for self learning of the concept and might not have practical use

My question is

1. can I use only recursive function and list comprehension to flatten a unknown level of nested list?
2. If 1 is possible, can I only use list comprehension + lambda function to get the same purpose?

So far this all I can get but it seems not working.

```
l=[1,[2,3],[4,5,[6,7,8,9]]] # assuming unknown level of nesting

def fun_d(x):
    return [fun_d(e) if isinstance(e,list) else e for e in x]

fun_d(l)

Out[25]: [1, [2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, 8, 9]]]
```

Comment: @dawg not sure this was a good duplicate as it is only one level deep, for which `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is a trivial solution. I wouldn't doubt there is probably a more appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @AChampion you're right

Comment: There are many good solutions to [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists/2158532#2158532) but not specific to using recursive  list comprehensions.

Comment: Consider then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44417443/298607) as a dup

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17338913/298607) as a dup...

Comment: @dawg both of those are just one-level deep flattens, the complexity added here is arbitrary nesting. As purely concept learning, fine - would never suggest this in practice.

Comment: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9], 10, 11]` is not one level

Comment: @dawg, Sorry, but I would define that as only 1 level of nesting. As in max depth of list within lists = 1. OP's example was a depth of 2 but asked for arbitrary depth. The dups you link to only solve for depth = 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can though it is a little strange:

```
def fun_d(x):
    return [i for e in x for i in (fun_d(e) if isinstance(e,list) else [e])]

In[] :
l=[1,[2,3],[4,5,[6,7,8,9]]]
fun_d(l)

Out[]:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You may want to use `Sequence` rather than `list` so other types of sequences would also be flattened.

```
from typing import Sequence

def fun_d(x):
    return [i for e in x for i in (fun_d(e) if isinstance(e, Sequence) and not isinstance(e, str) else [e])]
```

A named lambda is trivial, for a truly anonymous `lambda` you can use a [`y-combinator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus)

And just to show how ridiculous this is, an anonymous recursive `lambda`:

```
In []:
lis = [1,[2,3],[4,5,[6,[7,8],9]]]
(lambda f: f(f))(lambda f: (lambda fun_d: lambda x: [i for e in x for i in (fun_d(e) if isinstance(e, list) else [e])])(lambda x: f(f)(x)))(lis)

Out[]:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I don't believe I did, as this is recursive and your example is various levels of depth.

Comment: I would say the second example is closest to what I expected. But you are right, it is not elegant at all.

Comment: @AChampion, hats off to your lambda solution. I'd be studying that for a while.

Comment: @AChampion can you shed more lights on anounymous $lambda$? Is that result in more simpler/intuitive expression?

Comment: It's a [`y-combinator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). There isn't a simpler way to define an anonymous recursive function but this is trivial in python when you can add variable names, e.g.: `fun_d = lambda x: [i for e in x for i in (fun_d(e) if isinstance(e,list) else [e])]; fun_d(lis)`

Comment: @AChampion, great solution!, could you please point me to some good source to understand your second solution(y-combinator!). I know how to use lambda functions but didn't get a clear understanding of your solution as there is too many nesting in the code(is it possible for you write the same in multiple lines for quick understanding?)!

Comment: @AChampion, Also, I tried to run your solution2 on another sequence & it doesn't work, `A = (1,(2,3),(4,5,(6,(7,8),9)))` another, `A = ['image1', [[[[[4,5,[6,[7,8],9]]]]]], [[('image3', 'image3.1')], 'image4'], 'image5', (4,5,(6,7,8,9))]`, but it works for `A = [1,[2,3],[4,5,[6,[7,8],9]]]` ,   `A = ['image1', [[[['image2']]]], [['image3'], 'image4'], 'image5']` and `A= 'xyzzy'`. Any suggestion why it's not working on the first two inputs?

Comment: @anu you are using tuples not a list, as I mentioned test for `typing.Sequence` instead of a `list` for a more general solution, e.g. `from typing import Sequence` then `...  isinstance(e, Sequence) ...`

Comment: @AChampion, Great! I got it! Using `typing.Sequence` it works for both sequences `A = (1,(2,3),(4,5,(6,(7,8),9)))` and `A = [1, [[[[2]]]], [[3], 4], 5]`, but it given an error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` on input `A = ['str1', [[[['str2']]]], [['str3'], 'str4'], 'str5']` do you know the reason and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Strings will create problems with `Sequence` because they are considered a sequence, even a single character string, so you will need to guard against strings, e.g. `if isinstance(e, Sequence) and not isinstance(e, str)` you would have the same issue with `bytes` if you use them.

Comment: @AChampion, gotcha!., but if I use simple `list` instead of `typing.Sequence` it `doesn't give recursion error!` and flatten the above list too. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: If you use `list` it would not flatten `tuple`s, but that is your choice. You can explicitly test for `list`, `tuple` and any other sequences you want to support or you can support any `Sequence` and just exclude `str`.